# Java - Initialized ArrayList nullpointer

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception, null

I'm trying to understand why I get a nullpointer in this reduced code that I have. There are similar questions however other users didnt initialize their ArrayList. In my example I am initializing my ArrayList, however I still get a nullpointer when I try to add to it. Why is that?

```
public class Grid {

    private int x, y;

    private List<Node>[][] grid = null;

    public Grid(int x, int y) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        this.grid = new ArrayList[x][y];
    }

    public void addEle(Entity entity) {

        for (int x = 0; x <= 3; x++) {

            for (int y = 0; y <= 3; y++) {
                this.grid[x][y].add(new Node(entity));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get a nullpointer on the line, "this.grid[x][y].add(new Node(entity));", and I'm not sure why since my grid object isn't null.

This is a reduced example of my issue so here is the rest of my short-lived code:

Entity.java

```
public class Entity {
    public Entity() { }
}
```

Node.java

```
public class Node {

    Entity e;

    public Node(Entity e) {
        this.e = e;
    }
}
```

And lastly, my main class:

Driver.java

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Grid g = new Grid(4, 4);
        Entity e = new Entity();

        g.addEle(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.grid = new ArrayList[x][y];` creates a two dimensional array filled with **`null`** `ArrayList`(s).

Comment: @Elliott Frisch, Oh wow, that's a silly mistake. However I would have anticipated the size to start at zero. Is there a logical way around this or would I have to use a different data structure? I'm planning on adding a lot of elements to that particular array so I feel it would be inefficient to iterate through it to treat the nulls.

Comment: I'm actually trying to make something like, List<Node>[][] grid = new ArrayList<Entity>[x][y];, however Java is fighting back when i try.

Comment: Edit: **List<Node>[][] grid = new ArrayList<Node>[x][y];**

Answer (score 2):

The variable `grid` in your post is a two-dimensional array of `List`(s), and the default value for reference types is `null`. Thus, you create enough space to store `x` x `y` `List`(s); but you create no `List`(s) to store in your arrays. You could fill the array with `List`(s) in your constructor. Something like,

```
public Grid(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.grid = new ArrayList[x][y];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            this.grid[i][j] = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
}
```

I think I should also point out that `addEle` appears to be hardcoded to function with `4` elements only and you shadow the `x` and `y` fields. I think you wanted,

```
public void addEle(Entity entity) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            this.grid[i][j].add(new Node(entity));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for. I appreciate the clarification and will apply the logic to my code! Thanks for the second pointer as well -- I was just scurrying to get a minimal example so I can ask about the NPE :)